# How to fill a dataset with records marked for deletion in vb.net using a fox pro database?

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset, foxpro

I need to fill a dataset with deleted records to copy them into a backup location.  Im using the vfpoledb.1 adapter to load the database, adding it into a data set then cycling through it with for loops etc to import rows into the backup.

Is there a way to let VB see the deleted records in the database I am loading? so i can then import rows into the backup database and later pack database 1.

The purpose of this is to be working on an almost empty live database file to help with processing times.

Comment: Could you post your connection string/code?  I believe the issue is in the connection string.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724045/excluding-deleted-records-from-returned-set-using-vfpoledb-provider-for-foxpro-d

Comment: Yes thank you! exactly what i needed!

Comment: Mark it as answered then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set "deleted=false"; in the vfpoledb connection string.